# Show Textbox based on RadioButton selection or value when Page Loads

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So when I load a page I retrieve info from a DB and will check a radiobutton based on its value...

I need the textboxes to show initially - based on the radiobutton being already checked

works fine when I perform the click event, but I need to show the textboxes when the page loads because the 1st radiobutton is checked from the DB...

```
  <p>
  Show textboxes <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Show" checked="checked">
  Do nothing <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Nothing">
  </p>

  Wonderful textboxes:

  <div class="text"><p>Textbox #1 <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="30"></p></div>

  <div class="text"><p>Textbox #2 <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" maxlength="30"></p></div>
```

Here is my FIDDLE - DEMO
http://jsfiddle.net/rbla/5fq8q2bj/

here is the jquery using toggle

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".text").hide()
     $('[name=radio1]').on('change', function(){
        $('.text').toggle(this.value === 'Show');
     }).trigger('change');
 });
```

any ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your solution is not working is because you are going through all your radio inputs and then toggling the element based on its value—**regardless if it is checked or not**. So at runtime, this is what your script does:

1. Encounters the first radio element, triggers `onchange` event, fires `onchange` callback, and shows the `.text` element
2. Encounters the second radio element, triggers `onchange` event, fires `onchange` callback, and hides the `.text` element again

If you put a console log in your callback, you will realized that the `.text` element is shown and hidden in quick succession.

What you really want to do is only to perform the toggling when it is checked. Therefore, your example will work by simply enforcing a check that `this.checked` is truthy before performing the toggling:

```
$('[name=radio1]').on('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.text').toggle(this.value === 'Show');
  }
}).trigger('change');
```

See working example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".text").hide()
  $('[name=radio1]').on('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('.text').toggle(this.value === 'Show');
    }
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Show textboxes
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Show" checked="checked"> Do nothing
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Nothing">
</p>

Wonderful textboxes:

<div class="text">
  <p>Textbox #1
    <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="30">
  </p>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>Textbox #2
    <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" maxlength="30">
  </p>
</div>
```